# How to store checkboxes in browser cache (local storage) as checkboxes are generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table in my webpage. There are 3 columns in the table. First one is checkbox column, second is course code and third is course name. I just want to store the checkboxes in local cache so that when user refreshes the page, the selected checkboxes should be there.

Note:- The table is generated dynamically from XML file, as you refresh the page, the checkboxes are generated again as they are not static checkboxes.

```
function loadPage(xml) {
       var x, i, j, table, checkboxPrefix;
     xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
     table = "";


      x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("course");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        count++;
        xml_array.push(x[i].getElementsByTagName("courseCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        table += "<tr onclick='loadCourse(this)' class = '" +
         formatClass(x[i].getElementsByTagName("audience")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + " " +
         formatClass(x[i].getElementsByTagName("duration")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + " " +
         formatClass(x[i].getElementsByTagName("product")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) + " " +
         formatClass(getLanguage(x[i].getElementsByTagName("courseCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toString().substring(10))) + " " +
         formatClass(getMedium(x[i].getElementsByTagName("courseCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toString().charAt(2))) + " " +
        "'><***input type='checkbox' id='box"+ 
        i.toString()+
        "' class = 'selection'/>***</td><td class='row-ID2'><a class = 'course' href='#rowlinkModal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' id='" +
         x[i].getElementsByTagName("courseCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toString()
        + "' title='" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("courseTitle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toString() +
        "'>" + 
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("courseCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +

        "</a></td><td>"+
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("courseTitle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td></tr>";

      }

      document.getElementById("demo-body").innerHTML = table;

      document.getElementById("selectAllBoxes").checked = false;


    }
```

Comment: `local cache` ? Do you mean LocalStorage ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I have updated my question to add some more detail. Please have a look.

Comment: @APAD1 I have updated my question to add some more detail. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. session storage and local storage depending on your needs. Both of these use key value pairs.

Local Storage has no expiration date and is cleared by JavaScript or clearing Browser Cache.

Session storage is cleared when the browser window is closed.

So for your checkboxes you could do: (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('checkbox1', 'true');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('checkbox1');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('checkbox1');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Remember that the values are always stored as strings and to get them as booleans you will have to parse them.

```
var value = "true";
JSON.parse(value) === true; //true
```

Local storage works similarly :

```
localStorage.setItem('checkbox1', 'true');
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.